# MySQL Command Line Query times out at exactly 10 minutes - Amazon RDS Machine

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, timeout, rds

I have a pretty simple MySQL query that appears to be taking longer than 10 minutes to execute.

However, no matter what I run, the query times out at almost exactly 10 minutes everytime.

The same query on a smaller subset of the data in another table always completes and returns data.

Is there a way I can tell my Amazon RDS box with my database on it to not timeout ever?

The query is something as simple as this:

```
SELECT count(distinct userid) FROM testdb.`test_table_1`
WHERE description LIKE '%something%';
```

Comment: What exactly is your question ? Do you want to optimize this query to decrease it's execution time? Or do you want to increase a time after which the query timeouts ?

Comment: I want to increase the timeout period of the query, but I'm not sure if thats a MySQL setting or an RDS setting.

Comment: Try to increase `wait_timeout` and/or `interactive_timeout` values of MySql session using the `set` command - for example `set wait_timeout = 50000`. Default value for both variables is 28800 seconds (8 minutes). If this doesn't help, then you must dig into the details of RDS documentation.

Comment: Thanks for that pointer @kordirko - I set that value to close to its max and am trying my query again. Will let you know!

Comment: @jamis0n, was this ever resolved? you should close it by posting an answer.

Comment: FWIW I had the same problem while running a INSERT...SELECT query but the query keeps running behind the scenes even though my connection (to MySQL workbench) gets cut.